# How to choose the right tags for a question?

Tags: support, tags

What is the preferred approach to tagging a question?

In my case I am interested in questions about node.js. Node.js is ["a JavaScript runtime built on Chrome's V8 JavaScript engine"](https://nodejs.org/en/). So if you use the node.js API you write JavaScript code. How do you tag a question correctly?

1. `node.js` and `javascript`?
2. only `node.js` because it implies javascript?

I have seen both and even clear node.js questions that were only tagged with `javascript`.

But I did not find a clear policy or hint at how to handle this, also the tags help in the "new question" view does not state how to use tags (most specific vs. all that fit). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You may post (even implied tags) to reach a broader audience, as long these are closely related, and you're not _tag spamming_.

Comment: So if you edit a question would it be OK to add the `javascript` tag if it only has the `node.js` tag then? Or should you leave it the way the OP specified?

Comment: Yes that may probably OK, not obviously for your use case, but if a single minor followed tag that represents a niche for a particular programming language tag, it's OK to add the specific language tag IMHO (especially if code is shown in that question).

Comment: Language tag should take precedence.  If your question depends on others understanding that you're running in nodejs, then use that tag.  If your question can be answered by someone who assumes you're running in a browser, or by someone who doesn't even give the hosting environment a thought, then skip nodejs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the preferred approach to tagging a question?

I may sound utilitarian but you should use the tags that increase substantially the marginal chances of getting your question answered. That means that you have the best combination of public you can have. If javascript guys have to ask themselves "why the heck I'm reading this question?" obviously using [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) is counter productive.

As always, if you are interested in just searching related topics, the best way is using keywords, instead of tags, since tags are strongly biased towards potential answerers.

Comment: Thanks for clarification.